# Get word under tap from UIWebView using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm displaying some local web content and would like to get the word under the tap point. The single tap delegate is setup and I can get it to work great if I use a UITextView and load the HTML with a NSAttributedString and NSHTMLTextDocumentType, but I lose formatting such as paragraph spacing and small caps; adding a NSMutableParagraphStyle is without effect.

Using a UIWebView and loadHTMLString that includes JQuery, is there a way? There are several pages which show how to use JS to get the word under the cursor, such as the following:

[How to get a word under cursor using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444430/how-to-get-a-word-under-cursor-using-javascript)

[How to get word under cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855322/how-to-get-word-under-cursor)

[Get word under mouse pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373103/get-word-under-mouse-pointer)

[Is it possible to get the word under the mouse cursor in a `<textarea>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892723/is-it-possible-to-get-the-word-under-the-mouse-cursor-in-a-textarea)
[How to get word under cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855322/how-to-get-word-under-cursor)

But after several days, I've been unable to get it to work. My code:

```
var jsFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("webview", ofType: "js");
let jsData = NSString(contentsOfFile:jsFile!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding, error:nil) as! String
let returned = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(jsData)! as String
println("Returned \(returned).")
```

The word could be unicode with a different code range, but getting any word to work first would be wonderful.