# stop the cursor movement of an input range component

Tags: javascript

I use an input type="range" inside a form, which goes from the value -30 to the value 100:

```
<input type="range" min="-30" max="100" value="20">
```

Under certain conditions I would like to disable cursor movement when trying to move it to the left of zero
that is, for negative values.
My code involves adding and removing a listener:

```
 slider.addEventListener("mousemove", move);
    slider.oninput = function(){
      if(slider.value<0)
        slider.removeEventListener("mousemove", move);
    }
```

but that doesn't mean the cursor will stop moving. Is there a way to intervene on the standard behavior of this component?

Comment: You can't stop a user moving their cursor, what is the goal here, just to prevent the range from going below a certain value?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your attention. No, it's not that. I'm trying to emulate the real operation of a device and for this I need to block the movement of the cursor. I thought it could be done in some simple way.

Comment: The best I can think of would be to hide the user's native cursor and display your own fake cursor, which you could control the position of. Though that is generally considered a bad idea and isn't very user friendly.

Comment: If the goal is actually to stop the mouse from moving then you might be able to use Pointer Lock API - here's an existing question that asks the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415345/javascript-how-to-stop-mouse-movement

Comment: TBH still unclear what you're trying to achieve - stopping people moving the pointer would be very bad UX, but perhaps you have a reason.   But consider not everyone uses a "cursor" (which I assume you mean "pointer" as in "mouse pointer" - if not, then please clarify) - eg touchscreen

Comment: @DBS ok I'm taking this path you told me into consideration... but what should allow you to follow the real cursor and what should stop the tracking?

Comment: yes freedomn-m, you understood perfectly: prevent moving the pointer. But this link you passed me would block the mouse, which thinking about it I don't want to do. The mouse must continue to move and the pointer remain stationary.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you mean by "pointer" - do you mean the value "blob" on the range selector?  Is this what you're after: https://jsfiddle.net/78Lz6y9a/

Comment: Yes this! So you can do it with jquery. how does it work?

Comment: Oh, my bad - didn't notice this was [tag:javascript] only (I normally hang around [tag:jquery] - I've updated the answer to remove jquery - it's not much different I mostly use it as it's quicker to dev with (for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the value during the `input` event and then restrict the allowed values

```js
var el = document.getElementById("rng")
el.addEventListener('input', (e) => { if (e.target.value < 0) e.target.value = 0 });
```

```html
<input id="rng" type="range" min="-30" max="100" value="20">
```

---

Explanation: from [MDN input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)

> The `input` event is fired every time the value of the element changes. This is unlike the `change` event, which only fires when the value is committed.

at this point, you can check if the value is outside your allowed range (in the example `< 0`) and reset the value to the value you want.